# Solr Grouping For Categories / Sub-Categories

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm still very much a newbie in the realms of Solr.

I'm attempting create a query which groups by categories, returning a unique list of sub_categories. My schema looks something similar to the following:

```
+==============================================+
| id  | category | sub_category | Type         |
+-----+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1   | Apparel  | Pants        | Suede        |
| 2   | Apparel  | Pants        | Leather      |
| 3   | Apparel  | Pants        | Wind Pants   |
| 4   | Apparel  | Shirts       | Short-Sleeve |
| 5   | Apparel  | Shirts       | Long-Sleeve  |
| 6   | Sports   | Balls        | Soccer Ball  |
| 7   | Sports   | Balls        | Football     |
+-----+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

I'm interested in getting a return similar to the following, but am unsure on how to accomplish it. I can almost get here, the but problem is I am unable to get the sub_category column to return unique values. The example below *does* account for distinct sub_categories:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime:" 12,
  },
  "grouped": {
    "category": {
      "matches": 1,
      "groups": [
        {
          "groupValue": "Apparel",
          'docList": {
            "numFound": 2,
            'start': 0,
            'docs': [
              {"sub_category": "Pants"},
              {"sub_category": "Shirts"}
            ]
        },
        {
          "groupValue": "Sports",
          'docList": {
            "numFound": 2,
            'start': 0,
            'docs': [
              {"sub_category": "Balls"}
            ]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, you are using Solr 4.0+, I believe [facet pivoting](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting-1) is a better way to do this.

Try:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&facet.pivot=category,sub_category&facet=true&facet.field=category&rows=0`

*Update:* Hmm, but that's not going to give you the unique counts though :-? That will give you something like this, if that's OK with you:

```
+ Apparel [5]
|--- Pants [3]
|--- Shirts [2]
|
+ Sports [2]
|--- Balls [2]
```

Comment: i'm working on testing this. i am most definitely not tied to using grouping or the output format for grouping, so if facet pivoting works, i'm more than happy to use it!